# You know you love me

Tags: riddle, word

My sister made a riddle thingy for fun. I hope you like it:

> I may be enjoyed with ice,
>   but often preferred with fire.
>
> I can come with chocolate and crackers,
>   but it's fine when I come alone.
>
> Sometimes I am like a can,
>   sometimes I am an animal.
>
> I am usually spongy and soft,
>   and smell delightful.
>
> But if you ever forget me,
>   that will no longer be true.
>
> What am I?

**Note:** This is my first riddle. Feedback is appreciated.

Comment: you were to fast to modify your riddle

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you are

> marshmallow

I may be enjoyed with ice,

> you can put some on your ice-cream

but usually preferred with fire.

> but they are better as S'mores

I can come with chocolate,

> you need chocolate to make S'mores

but I'm fine when I come alone.

> but they are good alone as well

Sometimes I am like a can,

> usually shape like a can

sometimes I am an animal.

> and sometimes as an animal

I am usually spongy and soft,
and smell delightful.

> well those 2 are obvious

But if you ever forget me,
I may not be so good!

> if you forget it in the fire, it will burn
>  if you forget it, it will dry

Comment: This is correct. With ice means rocky road ice cream. With fire means toasted. But close enough.

Comment: It was pretty easy, wasn't it?

Comment: @mmking Yes, even without the edit

Comment: @mmking I didn't know about the rocky road ice cream. Looks yummy :)

Answer (score 1):

It could be

> tea.

*I may be enjoyed with ice,*

> Iced tea.

*but usually preferred with fire.*

> Tea is usually made with boiling water; boiling comes from heat, originally supplied by fire.

*I can come with chocolate,*

> Chocolate biscuits?

*but I'm fine when I come alone.*

> Ahhh, a nice cup of tea!

*Sometimes I am like a can,*

> A can of tea?

*sometimes I am an animal.*

> Not sure about this.

*I am usually spongy and soft,*

> Teabags or maybe tea leaves.

*and smell delightful.*

> Mmmm, the smell of freshly brewed tea!

*But if you ever forget me,

I may not be so good!*

> Forget a cup of tea for too long and it goes cold and icky.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible answer:

> cream.

*I may be enjoyed with ice,*

> Ice cream.

*but usually preferred with fire.*

> Creme brulee (burnt cream).

*I can come with chocolate,*

> Chocolate cream.

*but I'm fine when I come alone.*

> It's nice enough alone, I suppose.

*Sometimes I am like a can,

sometimes I am an animal.*

> Still not sure about these two.

*I am usually spongy and soft,*

> That could describe the consistency of cream.

*and smell delightful.*

> Maybe...

*But if you ever forget me, 
I may not be so good!*

> Forget cream for too long and it will go rancid and horrible.

Comment: You can get cans of it whipped.

Comment: That's not correct. Perhaps my riddle is too broad? Time to edit...

Comment: @alexmc And some people whip animals... No, that's stretching it too far.